# Strategy to upload profile photo from react app to server app

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, architecture, client-server, system-design

I am accepting profile photos from react app on ruby on rails application server. I am confused about which strategy should I follow. I can see the below two strategies.

1. Accept the image in the base 64 string format and convert it into the image file at the backend.
2. Accept the image in the form of form-data and stored it directly.

With the first approach, conversion is failing for small png images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Store where ? Are you trying to store the image as a blob into a database or uploading on a remote service such as Amazon S3 or MinIo ?